# page javascript onload can only use one function in a var?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I've written a basic page in html, putting this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

and the contents of my main.js are extremely simple:

```
var main = {

onload : function() {
    alert("HI");

    }

showSurprise : function() {
    alert("HI");

    }
}

window.onload = main.onload;
```

however, it seems that having these two functions exist at the same time causes neither of them to work, whether I set window.onload to the onload or the showSurprise function. If I delete one of them, it works fine.

Comment: You're missing a comma after the closing `}` of the "onload" function. Your browser developer console will have tried to show you that error, had you looked at it.

Comment: Is the missing comma just a copying error? If not, that explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pointy , what's the browser developer console? What I've been doing is write the code and refresh the file I opened in my browser

Comment: Hit F12 and be prepared for a world of new experiences :)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error. It should be:

```
var main = {
    onload: function() {
        alert("HI");

    },
    showSurprise: function() {
        alert("HI");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
var main = {
   onload: function() {
    alert("HI");

   },
  showSurprise: function() {
    alert("HI");
  }

 };    


 window.onload = main.onload();
```

You should pass it as a function.

Comment: The OP has the last part right. This answer will call *main.onload* immediately and assign the result (which is the value *undefined*) to the *onload* property of *window*.

Comment: it will execute what ever is in function body.

Comment: Of course it will, but **when** is it executed? And what value is assigned to *window.onload*? Try `console.log(window.onload)` immediately after the last statement. ;-)